# how to retrieve data from a column and produce that value into a new column

Tags: mysql, r, excel, output

I'm super new to R and have a question on how to do something. I listed the things that i got to work so ppl have an idea on what is going on. the thing im having trouble with is in bold.

-I have a data spreadsheet with 2 columns of data (End and CTCF). With the CTCF column having more cells

-I want to to take one value from the "End" column and subtract that value from each individual value in "CTCF" column (so i would have a bunch of products from each calculation)

-I want to then compare those products and find the miniumn absoulute value and the coresponding spot in the CTCF column

**-then place that value into a new column ajacent to the corresponding End value**.

I wrote a while loop (i know there is probably a WAY easier method) and got the calulation/comparison thing down. I was even able to output the location of the CTCF cell that contains my value of interest see below:

*

```
*data2<-read.csv("farah.csv")
head(data2)
periph_ctcfs<-list()
temp<-vector(mode="numeric", length = 356)
count<-1

  for(i in 1:length(data2$CTCF)) while (count<357)
                     {
                      End<-data2$End[count]
                      periph_ctcfs<-(End-data2$CTCF)
                      periph_ctcfs<-abs(periph_ctcfs)
                      periph_ctcfs<-which.min(periph_ctcfs)
                      print(periph_ctcfs)
                      temp[]<-data2$CTCF[periph_ctcfs]
                      count<-count + 1;

                      }*
```

- **The problem is when im trying to produce the new "periph_ctcfs" column, when im trying to insert it into the "temp" vector, the last printed number gets placed within all the cells of the "temp" vector. It feels like that each time the loop goes through its not inserting the retrieved value into "temp". Can anyone help? Thanks ive included a link to a photo (below) so you can get a visual on the layout of the data. Sorry for being a n00b.**

For clarity purposes:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO and to R! It helps (a lot) to have a [reproducible question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Please read that link, as well as the [StackOverflow help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The gist: if you can provide *small* and *representative* data that closely represents your problem, then perhaps we can help solve the concept-problem, and you can easily adapt it to your larger problem.

Comment: Can you provide a sample data?